# There was an error installation the ghost.py

Tags: python, pyqt, ghost.py

Downloading/unpacking ghost.py
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ghost.py (from versions: 0.1a, 0.1a2, 0.1a3, 0.1b, 0
.1b2)
Cleaning up...
No distributions matching the version for ghost.py
Storing complete log in C:\Users\user\pip\pip.log

installed:PySide 1.2,PyQt4-4.10.2-gpl-Py3.3-Qt4.8.4-x32.exe,python 3.3

How do i do next?

Comment: Please be much clearer about your problem, your environment and what you have done to install ghost.py, otherwise you not likely to get an answer. For example, did you use "pip install Ghost.py'? Which version of Windows

Comment: when i installed manually using the zip from github,Through the "python setup.py bulid&python setup.py install" command is successful,thank you for your comment

Answer (score 11):

You may want to try the `--pre` option of pip install, if you are getting this in your pip.log:

```
Ignoring link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/G/Ghost.py/Ghost.py-0.1b2.tar.gz#md5=53412b0c8691c3b404586c0baf47c612 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/Ghost.py/), version 0.1b2 is a pre-release (use --pre to allow).
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Ghost.py (from versions: 0.1a, 0.1a2, 0.1a3, 0.1b, 0.1b2)
```

Comment: For command line noobs like me here's how to use --pre:    pip install --pre Ghost.py